# Problem setting up github repository, touch not recognized in CMD

Tags: windows-7, github, repository, touch, command-prompt

When I get to the step:

touch README

I get the error

'touch' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

What does this mean?

I'm in Win 7 Home Premium command prompt.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you're working in git bash, not cmd.

Comment: Is it essential to use git bash? A couple of tutorials I'm following on git and rails don't indicate that it's essential. What's the main difference?

Answer (score 1):

The `touch` command updates the last-modified timestamp of the file to the current time, or if the file doesn't already exist, creates an empty file with the given name. This command does not exist (by default) in Windows, which is the reason you get that error message.

To get past this step, you can create a file called `README` in whatever way you feel most comfortable with. For example, you could use `notepad.exe` if you have no better alternative available.

Comment: How can you recommend notepad to anyone?  What did this poor fellow ever do to you?

Comment: Notepad is the only text editor guaranteed to exist on Windows 7 Home Premium. I've amended my comment. :)

Answer (score -1):

Use this code  in CMD and then touch your file

```
npm install touch-cli -g
```